# I'm thinking of starting a Angular project.. should I wait for version 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I've heard that Angular 2 is a major update.  Does anyone know if my project started in Angular 1.3 be easily upgradable to 2 when it comes out.  Don't wanna throw away code.

Comment: Start the project! That'd be like Jimi Hendrix saying "wonder if I should learn guitar on this right handed guitar or wait until I can get a left handed one" Start the project, get your structure started, get your logic and functions built. I doubt there will be much a problem when the new version ships, as it is the same language... they might deprecate some things on you, but fixing that will be a breeze.

Comment: Why the downvote??  Just trying to get some info from the community on 1.3 -> 2.0

Comment: Gary.. first of all it's not like Jimi Hendrix wondering if he should buy a guitar because guitars don't become obsolete or change over time.  Development time is very costly and if there is no forward conversion plan on a major upgrade you've essentially killed your project and wasted money.  According to gfunk this in fact is the case.  Doing what you say would be more like starting to build your house out of a framing material that the supplier discontinues in the middle of your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Davin Tryon's answer, here is an article that explains some of the changes.  As you can see it would require a pretty major rewrite to change from 1.3 -> 2.0.  http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/AngularJS-2-Status-Preview/

Answer (score 3):

As I understand there is no 1.3 -> 2.0 upgrade path planned by the Angular developers.  So, no 1.3 is not going to be upgradable.

Version 2.0 is not likely to ship until late next year (late 2015, or beyond).  Therefore, if you want to do a project in the next year, it will have to be 1.3.

It looks like 2.0 will be a major departure from 1.3. For example, there will not be `$scope` or `controller`!!  So, 2.0 is a re-write not really another version.

The [video from ng-europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI) explains how different 2.0 is planned to be.